# Interpreting the Values of Confusion Matrix from machine learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I used confusion_matrix() to evaluate the model that has been trained to detect the DDoS attack.
The result of confusion matrix is like below with my test data set.
I believe that False neg value should be not 0 if it correctly detected the attack that is not DDoS.

[image]

Below is the code that I have implemented my ML model. Could you please give me a suggestion to make the model correctly check the benign attacks?

```
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=7))  # Input Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))   # hidden Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))   # hidden Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))     # Last Layer for output


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

CSV_FILE = "ddos.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE)
df.loc[(df.Label == "ddos"), "Label"] = 1.0
df.loc[(df.Label == "Benign"), "Label"] = 0.0

# Data set
x_train = np.array(df[["Flow Duration", "Tot Fwd Pkts", "TotLen Fwd Pkts",
                       "Flow IAT Mean","Flow IAT Std" ,"Flow IAT Max", "Flow IAT Min"]])

x_train = x_train.astype(float)
normalized_x = preprocessing.normalize(x_train)

y_train = np.array(df[["Label"]])
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype = 'float')
normalized_y = preprocessing.normalize(y_train)

hist = model.fit(normalized_x, normalized_y, epochs=3, batch_size=128)

y_pred = model.predict(x_train)
y_pred = preprocessing.normalize(y_pred)

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, np.rint(y_pred))
```

Notice that my dataset is **not** imbalanced, i.e. it has exactly 50% DDoS and 50% Normal traffic information.

Answer (score 0):

Although such questions cannot actually be answered with any degree of certainty, there are indeed some serious issues with your code.

**First**, you should **not** normalize your labels `y_train`; this is a binary classification problem, and the labels are expected to be exactly `0/1`. **Remove** the following lines:

```
normalized_y = preprocessing.normalize(y_train)
y_pred = preprocessing.normalize(y_pred)
```

change the labels into integers (not floats), i.e.:

```
df.loc[(df.Label == "ddos"), "Label"] = 1
df.loc[(df.Label == "Benign"), "Label"] = 0
```

and your model fit to:

```
hist = model.fit(normalized_x, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=128)
```

**Second**, although you train with `normalized_x`, you subsequently request predictions with `x_train`, which is again wrong; your predictions should be:

```
y_pred = model.predict(normalized_x)
```

**Third**, dropout should not be used by default, but only if we have signs of overfitting - but to do so, our model has first to be able to start learning something, which is not the case here. **Comment out** all dropout layers, and start putting them back into the model only in case of overfitting.

**Last**, you should start with the default settings of Adam, which usually (and reportedly) work well out of the box, i.e.:

```
optimizer=Adam()
```

And of course you should consider running the model for more than `epochs=3`.